# Zsh: How to generate (glob) filename excepting specific extension?

Tags: linux, zsh

I want to `ls` files that doesn't have extension `*.m2ts` nor `*.mp4`.

Of course, I can get BOTH `*.m2ts` and `*.mp4` files via `ls *.(m2ts|mp4)` . How can I negate this glob?

Comment: I don't think there is a proper way to put this into a glob. How about using `ls | egrep -v '\.(m2ts|mp4)$'`

Comment: There is `^` qualifier to negate glob, but it seems not working this case...

Comment: Have you checked `ls`'s `-I/--ignore` option? `ls -I "*.m2ts" -I "*.mp4"` should also do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found simple solution:

```
ls -d ^*.(mp4|m2ts)
```

This worked well. `-d` option seems to be mandatory.

```
       -d, --directory
              list directories themselves, not their contents
```

Comment: This requires `setopt extended_glob` to be set, just FYI.

Comment: If you just want to display the filenames, no need to use `ls` at all. Use the zsh builtin `print` instead.

Comment: `*.^(mp4|m2ts)` should work too. And with `setopt KSH_GLOB` in effect, `*.!(mp4|m2ts)`. Or even `*~*.(mp4|m2ts)`